# DEADLINE_EXCEEDED when Airflow runs spark jobs

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

We are running an Airflow pipeline that executes several spark jobs on dataproc. One of these jobs takes 3-4 hours to complete. We are seeing the following error messages in the Airflow logs, even though the spark job succeeds:

```
HttpError 504 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/our-project/regions/global/jobs/our_job_20170930_5c0ee1ff?alt=json returned "Deadline expired before operation could complete
```

This causes Airflow to retry the task (which actually succeeded).

I see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rpc/google.rpc) that the DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error "may be returned even if the operation has completed successfully. For example, a successful response from a server could have been delayed long enough for the deadline to expire".

So my question is: is there any configuration parameter we can tweak to avoid these timeouts and retries?

### EDIT:

In the job output in Dataproc we see a log message, just before it finishes:

```
17/10/06 08:33:51 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus: SparkListenerBus has already stopped! Dropping event SparkListenerExecutorMetricsUpdate(10,WrappedArray())
```

Which further gives us the impression that the spark-job ran to completion, and then when it tried to report back that it's done there was nobody listening.

Comment: I suggest implementing low-level retries for each RPC (GetJob, SubmitJob, etc). Client code should trap HTTP errors and retry any 500 and above status.

Comment: Simply setting num_retries on execute() may be exactly what you're looking for: https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest-class.html#execute

Comment: The thing is we don't want to retry, the underlying job actually succeeded. I think what happens is that we get a 504 because Airflow **thinks** the job failed after a certain amount of time. What we need is for Airflow to wait longer (if I understand correctly what's going on under the hood).

Comment: Airflow is not setting a timeout for the HTTP call -- the error is actually coming from Dataproc. Under the hood Dataproc has to query other services, such as a database. If one of those dependencies takes too long to respond, Dataproc will propagate the error as an HTTP 504. tix is saying that Airflow should catch and retry 504 here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataproc_hook.py#L41. That being said, DEADLINE_EXCEEDED should be a transient (and pretty rare) error. Are you seeing it consistently?

Comment: That makes sense, I see in the stack-trace `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataproc_hook.py", line 41, in wait_for_done`. And yes, we see this error several times a week (the pipeline runs every day).
I'm suspecting this happens when the spark job writes the output to the db, which takes a while. Again, we don't want to retry the job because we actually get the results in the db. We would like to avoid these timeouts.